# Drupal Views:Add condition in where clause where the value is a field in hook_alter_query

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-hooks, civicrm

I am trying to add a condition to a query like:

civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship.id <> civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship_1.id

but for the second field drupal takes it as a string so it always result into

civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship.id <> 'civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship_1.id'

I've tried to play with the numerical value with no success.

Any idea how can I do this? May be with another hook? any tip will be welcome!

My code:

```
        $view->query->where[2]["conditions"][0]["field"] = "civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship_1.id";
        $view->query->where[2]["conditions"][0]["operator"] = "IS NULL";
        $view->query->where[2]["conditions"][0]["value"] = "";

        $view->query->where[2]["conditions"][1]["field"] = "civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship.id";
        $view->query->where[2]["conditions"][1]["operator"] = "IS NULL";
        $view->query->where[2]["conditions"][1]["value"] = "";

        $view->query->where[2]["conditions"][2]["field"] = "civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship.id";
        $view->query->where[2]["conditions"][2]["value"] ="civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship_1.id";
        $view->query->where[2]["conditions"][2]["numeric"] = "1";
        $view->query->where[2]["conditions"][2]["operator"] = "<>";

        $view->query->where[2]["type"] = "OR";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like

```php
    function my_hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)
    {
      if ($view->name == 'my_hook') {
        $alias = $query->add_table('civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship','civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship_1');
        $query->add_where_expression(0,'civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship.id <> civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship_1.id');
        dpm($query); //dumps object to admin with devel module
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!! Sorry for the late answer but as the solution came a bit late I had things to finish before I could came back to this one! But it worked perfectly! Thx

Comment: I am interested in how to implement the "OR" at the bottom of his example.